# How to invoke encrypted password inside ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can I encrypt the password in Ansible for executing windows playbook?

Kerberos authentication in enabled

When playbook is edited others shouldn`t see encrypted password

Comment: You can use ansible vault for that.

Comment: - name: start of the windows update
  hosts: win
  serial: 1
  connection: winrm
  become_method: runas
  become_user: Sam
  vars:
        ansible_become_password: "*!,W:t?5qc%{~9/" , How can i add the password variable inside playbook? I have read vault but we`re not using Ansile tower.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data-on-ubuntu-16-04 this link explains the concept in detail

Answer (score 1):

Since Ansible 2.4 you can encrypt strings with `ansible-vault` and put in in playbooks and roles. You have to create vault-password and run the following code:

```
$ ansible-vault encrypt_string --ask-vault-pass --stdin-name 'password'
New Vault password: 
Confirm New Vault password: 
Reading plaintext input from stdin. (ctrl-d to end input)
SecretPassword123
password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          65316563643063333532303262343166333232313034303333386330333635313433383236656337
          3634653534353630663131656531663162376161333030350a363434343961666535316366643135
          33326462393934633930336261373532666239653834316235666638613164616538306536396634
          6432343763336135320a386263663736396164343065323233656134656262653238643038633665
          39363631666630623062356238663165343737346535396237646461303938383230
Encryption successful
```

Then paste your encrypted password to your variables, like this:

```
username: "user01"
password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          65316563643063333532303262343166333232313034303333386330333635313433383236656337
          3634653534353630663131656531663162376161333030350a363434343961666535316366643135
          33326462393934633930336261373532666239653834316235666638613164616538306536396634
          6432343763336135320a386263663736396164343065323233656134656262653238643038633665
          39363631666630623062356238663165343737346535396237646461303938383230
some_other_variable: "1234"
one_more_variable: "4444"
```

And run your playbooks. But don't forget to use your vault-password when run `ansible-playbook`. It can be used as a parameter of `--ask-vault-pass` or in the file described in `--vault-password-file`